# The --require and -r flags are deprecated

Tags: nodejs, npm

Al querer ejecutar las pruebas de AVA en Windows utilizando este comando:

```
npm run test
```

que a su vez ejecuta este comando:

```
"SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" & nyc ava --require babel-register test/**-test.js $AVA_ARGS",
```

me lanza este error:

> The --require and -r flags are deprecated. Requirements should be
>   configured in package.json - see documentation.

el comando me funcionaba correctamente la ultima vez que lo ejecute, he buscado en la documentacion de npm como recomienda el error pero no he podido encontrar nada que me solucione el problema, ¿cual es la nueva etiqueta que reemplaza a --require? gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si acaso a alguien más le llega a pasar, se soluciona con sólo eliminar esta parte del comando:

```
--require babel-register
```

quedando así:

```
"SET \"NODE_ENV=test\" & nyc ava test/**-test.js $AVA_ARGS",
```